Spring Boot and MapStruct: Circular Dependency Issue with Many-to-Many Relationship between Post and Tag Entities
I am developing a Spring Boot application using MapStruct for mapping between DTOs and entities. The application has a Many-to-Many relationship between Post and Tag entities. When I send a request to create a Post without tags, it works perfectly. However, when I include tagIds in the request, I encounter a  and foreign key constraint violations. Despite ensuring that the tags exist in the database, the error persists. I have tried various solutions, including using  and  in MapStruct, but the issue continues. I need help resolving this problem.StackOverflowError@Named@BeanMapping
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:
Ensured that the 'tagIds' exist in the database by querying the tag table and verifying the records.
Updated the PostMapper and TagMapper to handle circular dependencies using @Named and @BeanMapping annotations in MapStruct.
Simplified the TagMapper to map Set directly to Set.
I expected these changes to allow the creation of a Post with associated Tags without errors. However, when I include tagIds in the request, I still encounter a StackOverflowError and foreign key constraint violations.
What actually happened?
When I send a request to create a Post without tagIds, the Post is created successfully, and I receive the expected response.
Request without Tags:
{
    "title": "Oracle OCI",
    "content": "Oracle OCI",
    "subCategoryId": 9, 
    "tagIds": [],
    "author": "Fsengul",
    "featuredImageUrl": "http://example.com/imageora.jpg",
    "publishedDate": "2024-05-19T12:00:00",
    "isActive": true,   
    "isFeatured": false,
    "metaDescription": "A detailed post about oracle variables.",
    "metaKeywords": "oracle"
}

Response:
{
    "id": 21,
    "title": "Oracle OCI",
    "content": "Oracle OCI",
    "subCategoryId": 9,
    "tags": [],
    "author": "Fsengul",
    "featuredImageUrl": "http://example.com/imageora.jpg",
    "publishedDate": "2024-05-19T12:00:00",
    "viewCount": 0,
    "likeCount": 0,
    "isActive": true,
    "isFeatured": false,
    "metaDescription": "A detailed post about oracle variables.",
    "metaKeywords": "oracle",
    "createdDate": "2024-05-20T11:47:44.544941",
    "lastModifiedDate": null
}

When I include tagIds in the request, I receive a long list of "No static resource api" messages and the following error:
Request with Tags:
{
    "title": "Oracle OCI",
    "content": "Oracle OCI",
    "subCategoryId": 9, 
    "tagIds": [1, 2],
    "author": "Fsengul",
    "featuredImageUrl": "http://example.com/imageora.jpg",
    "publishedDate": "2024-05-19T12:00:00",
    "isActive": true,   
    "isFeatured": false,
    "metaDescription": "A detailed post about oracle variables.",
    "metaKeywords": "oracle"
}

Console Output:
No static resource api/No static resource api/... could not execute statement [ERROR: insert or update on table "post_tags" violates foreign key constraint "fkp7cfgjsujc2vl3p88qfqkpws6" Ayrıntı: Key (tag_id)=(2) is not present in table "tag".] [insert into post_tags (post_id, tag_id) values (....................]
Despite ensuring the tagIds exist in the database, the error persists. I need help to resolve this issue so that I can create a Post with associated Tags without encountering errors.
Entities
Post Entity
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sub_category_id", nullable = false)
    private SubCategory subCategory;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "post_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String author;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String featuredImageUrl;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDateTime publishedDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int viewCount = 0;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int likeCount = 0;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Boolean isFeatured;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String metaDescription;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String metaKeywords;

    // Getters and Setters
}

Tag Entity
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Boolean isActive;

    // Getters and Setters
}

DTOs
PostRequest
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Set;

public class PostRequest {

    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Long subCategoryId;
    private Set<Long> tagIds;
    private String author;
    private String featuredImageUrl;
    private LocalDateTime publishedDate;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private Boolean isFeatured;
    private String metaDescription;
    private String metaKeywords;

    // Getters and Setters
}

PostResponse
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Set;

public class PostResponse {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Long subCategoryId;
    private Set<TagResponse> tags;
    private String author;
    private String featuredImageUrl;
    private LocalDateTime publishedDate;
    private int viewCount;
    private int likeCount;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private Boolean isFeatured;
    private String metaDescription;
    private String metaKeywords;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    // Getters and Setters
}


TagRequest
public class TagRequest {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Boolean isActive;

    // Getters and Setters
}

TagResponse
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Set;

public class TagResponse {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Set<PostResponse> posts;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    // Getters and Setters
}

Mapper Interfaces
TagMapper
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.Set;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface TagMapper {

    TagMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(TagMapper.class);

    TagResponse toTagResponse(Tag tag);

    Set<TagResponse> toTagResponses(Set<Tag> tags);

    Tag toTagEntity(TagRequest tagRequest);
}

PostMapper
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {TagMapper.class})
public interface PostMapper {

    PostMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PostMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "subCategory.id", target = "subCategoryId")
    @Mapping(source = "tags", target = "tags")
    PostResponse toPostResponse(Post post);

    @Mapping(source = "subCategoryId", target = "subCategory.id")
    @Mapping(target = "tags", ignore = true)
    Post toPostEntity(PostRequest postRequest);
}

Repositories
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import java.util.Set;

public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long> {
    Set<Tag> findAllById(Iterable<Long> ids);
}

Service
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SubCategoryRepository subCategoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PostMapper postMapper;

    @Transactional
    public PostResponse createPost(PostRequest postRequest) {
        Post post = postMapper.toPostEntity(postRequest);

        post.setSubCategory(subCategoryRepository.findById(postRequest.getSubCategoryId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("SubCategory not found")));

        Set<Tag> tags = tagRepository.findAllById(postRequest.getTagIds()).stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        if (tags.size() != postRequest.getTagIds().size()) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("One or more tags not found. Make sure all tags exist in the database.");
        }
        post.setTags(tags);

        post = postRepository.save(post);
        return postMapper.toPostResponse(post);
    }
}


Controller
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/posts")
@Validated
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @PostMapping
    public PostResponse createPost(@Valid @RequestBody PostRequest postRequest) {
        return postService.createPost(postRequest);
    }
}

Database State
I have verified that the Tag entities with IDs 1 and 2 exist in the database. Here is the state of the Tag table:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Java-Spring-Boot",
        "description": "Java Tag",
        "posts": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "createdDate": "2024-05-19T17:56:21.93962",
        "lastModifiedDate": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Java-EE",
        "description": "Java EE Tag",
        "posts": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "createdDate": "2024-05-19T18:34:05.697195",
        "lastModifiedDate": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Devops",
        "description": "Devops",
        "posts": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "createdDate": "2024-05-19T19:20:25.294445",
        "lastModifiedDate": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Spring MVC",
        "description": "Spring MVC",
        "posts": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "createdDate": "2024-05-19T21:11:45.590621",
        "lastModifiedDate": null
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Python",
        "description": "Python",
        "posts": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "createdDate": "2024-05-19T21:26:10.882249",
        "lastModifiedDate": null
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Academic",
        "description": "Academic",
        "posts": [],
        "isActive": true,
        "createdDate": "2024-05-19T21:26:28.042141",
        "lastModifiedDate": null
    }
]

Despite these records being present, the error persists when attempting to create a Post with associated tags.
Question
How can I resolve the StackOverflowError and foreign key constraint violation when creating a Post with associated Tags using Spring Boot and MapStruct? What am I missing or doing wrong in my current setup?
Thank you for your help!

Can you please show the stack trace (strip down the repeating parts but make it clear what is repeating). My guess is an infinite recursion while mapping PostResponse#tags and TagResponse#posts i.e. you try to map the PostResponse which includes a TagResponse which includes the original PostResponse which includes the TagResponse which includes the PostResponse etc.

Also, can you please share your PostRepository?

@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
}

Can you please [edit] your question and include your TagRepository (or similar)? Specifically, your findAllById method would be interesting. Also, can you maybe try adding the Post to its Tags before saving it?

Try to add  @JsonIgnore property for ManyToMany realtionships. Your PostResponse has TagResponse which has  PostResponse - this is causing stackoferflow exception. Try to add @JsonIgnore to the set included in TagResponse or PostResponse. In addition error with constaint - you have wrong table names: @Table(name = "tags"), error is speaking of: "tag" without "s".
